# Laravel check if user have user name if not show user id excel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel-excel plugin.

I am building a mapping in excel. And i want if user name does not exist show only the `user_id` if the user press download the excel file. I have tried some methods but without result.

```
    public function map($user): array
{
    return[
        $user->id,
        $user->user->name != $user->user_id,
        $user->organization->name,
        $user->course_id,
        $user->start_date,
        $user->end_date,
        $user->completed,
        $user->score,
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ternary oratory

```php
public function map($user): array
{
    return [
        $user->id,
        isset($user->user->name) && !empty($user->user->name)  ? $user->user->name : $user->user_id,
        $user->organization->name,
        $user->course_id,
        $user->start_date,
        $user->end_date,
        $user->completed,
        $user->score,
    ];
}
```

Comment: @RonvanderHeiden isset can also check if key exists, it comes handly in nosql databases, using only empty will break the code in case of nosql dbs, though it is ok to only use empty in sql dbs